# Transferring files from node A to all other nodes (remote hosts) parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

Our Jenkins jobs are currently downloading all the components to build every build from artifactory, this downloading is wasting a lot of build time, therefore, I've started to work on a tool that will download all the components every time there is a new version and when the build start i will use the external cache on the hosts instead of downloading it.

After downloading the files ( 17 GB ) the to node locally I'm facing an issue with how to share those files with all the other nodes,
at first, I've tried to parallel-rsync all the files to the other nodes but its took a lot of time on with python multithreading  ( 24 nodes ) and then I've tried to use parallel-ssh in order to tell each node to download the files its self but it also took a lot of time,
then i thought about triggering lots of jobs from Jenkins buts its may fill up my queue.
and at least I thought about just trigger the jobs to the other hosts with & but if I do that I may not have any information in case the download failed on the job.

Any suggestions about how I can do this activity in the most recommended way?
Thanks